# Spring Testing: How to enable auto-scan of beans

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-test

For example, now in each test class I have to do

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

I want to get rid of

```
 @ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

and want Spring to scan all the beans in my project.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have your spring configuration in an xml file you would use something like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:applicationContext.xml")
```

If you use Java Config then you would use

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Config.class)
```

I used generic names in the above samples, you'll of course need to adapt to your project's configuration.

In both cases Spring's component scanning will need to be enabled for Spring to pickup the annotated classes.

Answer (score 64):

You can do this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void testSomething() {

  }

  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan("basepackage")
  public static class SpringConfig {

  }
}
```

By default `@ContextConfiguration` will look for static inner classes annotated with `@Configuration`, which is why this set up will just work.

You can get rid of loader param altogether, that is not required

Comment: What if I use `@Before` annotation on a method in a test? Will that method actually be executed before `@Configuration`?

Comment: This is trying to look for xml in my case `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [mypackage/MyTest-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
`

Comment: I prefer to use this annotation in "integration" tests instead to start the WEB app. By this way tests execute faster.

Answer (score 5):

You can also simply add `@SpringBootTest` if using Spring Boot.

Comment: No sure why this was down-voted. Adding this avoids having to use @ContextConfiguration at all.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment! I assumed it was because the OP didn't mention Spring Boot, so I kind of went out in a limb.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it leads to new error messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @TestConfiguration 
    @ComponentScan("basepackage")
    public class TestConfig{

    }
```

Adding a config class lets spring to load application context.
This solved this issue for me.